# MapBox queryRenderedFeatures return too much values

Tags: android, mapbox, geojson

I'm using MapBox SDK for Android to display a geojson file on top of a map.

From geojson "features", I create some "fillLayer", each of them is associate to a value from properties object in geojson.
I fill each layer with a colour corresponding to the value.

To get this value from a specific localisation I use the API call:
"queryRenderedFeatures"

Here is how I create layer from previously created geojsonSource object:

```
for (int i=0; i < list_value_geojson.size(); i++){
    Map.Entry<Integer, GeoJsonSource> entry = list_value_geojson.get(i);
        mapboxMap.addSource(entry.getValue());
        FillLayer fillLayer = new FillLayer(entry.getValue().getId(), entry.getValue().getId());
        fillLayer.setProperties(PropertyFactory.fillColor(Color.parseColor(hashMapColors.get(entry.getKey()))));
        mapboxMap.addLayer(fillLayer);
}
```

Here, how I use queryRenderedFeatures from a "Location" object:

```
final PointF pixel = my_mapboxMap.getProjection().toScreenLocation(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()));
List<Feature> features = my_mapboxMap.queryRenderedFeatures(pixel);
```

### My problem

*queryRenderedFeatures* function, sometime, return me too much Features, exemple: I search for a specific location and I get three features, but only the third one has the correct value, the two first have the value from the layer just next to.

### Exemple

[image: Wrong value]

The good value is 174 not 181, colour should be dark bue.

Here is *queryrenderedfeatures* result:

```
0 = {Feature@6242} : {"value":181}
1 = {Feature@6243} : {"value":181}
2 = {Feature@6244} : {"value":174}
```

### Question

How do I know which feature should I use?
MapBox "know" because the colour of the display layer is correct.

Thank you a lot for having read me.

Comment: For the moment, I use the value how occur the less

Answer (score 1):

You can limit the layer you are querying by passing in the layer id as a parameter in the `queryRenderedFeatures` method. Checkout [this example](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-android-demo/blob/master/MapboxAndroidDemo/src/main/java/com/mapbox/mapboxandroiddemo/examples/query/SelectBuildingActivity.java#L55).

Comment: How would I know the layer ID? I know the layer id list but I don't know which one contain the value for the current position